# Octave - Adding '\n' to String Array is Not Creating a New Line

Tags: arrays, string, octave

I want to change `','` character to `'\n'` and save it to the text file

All files are in this format:

```
546,234,453,685,.....,234
```

I want to make it like:

```
546

234

453

685

...

234
```

My initiation to this problem is like this:

```
fid=fopen(files{i});
strArr=fscanf(fid,'%s');

newstrArr=strrep(strArr,',','\n');

% Take each .txt input
for j=1:length(newstrArr)  
   Array=[Array newstrArr(j)];   
endfor
```

Let me explain step by step:

1st I open the current text file

```
 fid=fopen(files{i});
```

2nd I find the strings in text file

```
strArr=fscanf(fid,'%s');
```

Please Note that you can't replace %s with %d. (Correct me if I am wrong)

3rd I replace commas with newline character

```
newstrArr=strrep(strArr,',','\n');
```

4th I add each character to a new array with for loop

```
for j=1:length(newstrArr)  
   Array=[Array newstrArr(j)];   
endfor
```

However When I display, using;

```
disp(Array);
```

I have this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSM5K.jpg)

How can I properly replace the commas with newlines?

Regards

Comment: If you are on GNU/Linux this would be a job for "tr" or "sed"

Comment: @Andy "tr" or "sed" , never heard before, I will definitely search and learn about it, thanks for knowledge

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you are inserting a literal `'\n'` (the characters `\` and `n`) and not a newline character. This is because in Octave, [a single-quote enclosed string ignores escape sequences](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Escape-Sequences-in-String-Constants.html#Escape-Sequences-in-String-Constants). If you want Octave to respect escape sequences you could use a double-quoted string which will convert `\n` into a newline.

```
strrep(strArr, ',', "\n");
```

Or if you want your code to be MATLAB-compatible, you'll want to instead use `char(10)` (an actual new-line character). This is because MATLAB does not have double-quote enclosed strings.

```
output = strrep(strArr, ',', char(10));
```

Another option would be to split your input at the `,` and use `sprintf` to add the newlines (it'll treat `\n` as a newline)

```
values = strsplit(strArr, ',');
output = sprintf('%s\n', values{:});
```

If you just want to save each entry to a new line in a file, you can use `fprintf` instead.

```
values = strsplit(strArr, ',');
fout = fopen('output.txt', 'w');
fprintf(foug, '%s\n', values{:});
fclose(fout);
```

Comment: Definitely ' char(10) ' improved my solution. You are the man.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to replace "," with newline simply do

```
in = fileread ("yourfile");
out = strrep (in, ",", "\n")
out = 546
234
453
685
234
```

Btw, see the difference between "\n" (in GNU Octave a newline) and '\n' (literally \n)

Comment: I couldn't understand you answer but I do it following way 

newstrArr=strrep(strArr,',',char(10)); 

and it gave me an input like 54\n234\n...........

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `regexprep()`, this has the advantage of being MATLAB compatible. Assuming that the newline convention you want is `\n`, then

```
regexprep('123,456,789',',','\n')

ans = 123
456
789
```

When output to a file via `fprintf()` the result looks like

```
123
456
789
```

provided the text editor understands the newline convention.